# Locale based on the user's Preferences

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony4

I try to set the locale based on user settings (i.e "language" property in User Entity) but it failed on first request (with user authenticated) because the LocaleListener (and TranslatorListener also) is called before FirewallListener.

I tried this example [Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html#setting-the-locale-based-on-the-user-s-preferences) but on first request default locale (in config) is "fr", my user defined his language in "en" and finally the page is displayed in french.

The trick could be to create a listener (called before LocaleListener or TranslatorListener) to get the user's locale from another method, but I don't find which method to use. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sylius uses a custom LocaleListener and changes TranslatorListener priority https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services/listeners.xml#L74

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have overridden TranslatorListener definition using Compiler Pass, now called after FirewallListener.

```
class OverrideTranslatorListenerCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        if ($container->hasDefinition('translator_listener')) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition('translator_listener');
            $definition->setTags([
                'kernel.event_listener' => [
                    [
                        'event' => KernelEvents::REQUEST,
                        'method' => 'onKernelRequest',
                        'priority' => 2, // 10 before
                    ],
                    [
                        'event' => KernelEvents::FINISH_REQUEST,
                        'method' => 'onKernelFinishRequest',
                        'priority' => 0, // not changed, needed because overridding ALL tags
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

And my subscriber

```
class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    public function __construct(..., Security $security)
    {
        ...

        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (null !== ($user = $this->security->getUser())) {
            $request->setLocale($user->getLanguage());

            return;
        }

        ...
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 4],
        ];
    }
```

I hope this can help ;)